# Resolution for exterior power of a quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra, quotient-spaces, exterior-algebra

Let us assume that we have exact sequence of vector spaces:

$$0\to U\to V\to W\to 0.$$

We can think of $0\to U\to V$ as a resolution of $W$.

> Can we construct some canonical resolution of $\Lambda^n W$ in terms of some functors (like $\Lambda^ k U, S^l V$) of $U$ and $V$?

For example we have

$$U\otimes \Lambda^{n-1}V\to \Lambda^n V\to \Lambda^n W\to 0$$

is exact. Here the first map is multiplication ant the second is natural projection. Can we extend this sequence to the left?

Comment: You can probably work inductively, using that $V\cong U\oplus W$  (non-canonically) and using the formula for expanding an exterior product, perhaps? This will tell you the summands that need to be eliminated to get $\Lambda^n(W)$, provided that you know how to treat $\Lambda^j$ for $j<n$.